# Are morphisms in a stable $\infty$-category generated by split injections?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

I've seen it stated in the $\infty$-categorical literature (without proof or reference) that every object in the $\infty$-category $\operatorname{Fun}(\Delta^1, \mathcal{C})$ of morphisms in a stable $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$ is a geometric realization of arrows of the form $A \rightarrow A \oplus B$. I may be missing some assumptions, but those should be "mild". Why is this the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any map $f:A\to B$ fits in a cofiber sequence of arrows $(0\to A)\to (A\to A\oplus B)\to (A\to B)$

In other words, any map is a cofiber of split inclusions. But now cofibers (as any colimit, by the Bousfield-Kan formula) can be rewritten as geometric realizations of coproducts of the involved terms, and thus we can conclude (coproducts of split inclusions are clearly split inclusions).

Comment: Maxime has suggested Corollary 12.3 of @article {MR4587313,
    AUTHOR = {Shah, Jay},
     TITLE = {Parametrized higher category theory},
   JOURNAL = {Algebr. Geom. Topol.},
  FJOURNAL = {Algebraic \& Geometric Topology},
    VOLUME = {23},
      YEAR = {2023},
    NUMBER = {2},
     PAGES = {509--644},
      ISSN = {1472-2747,1472-2739},
   MRCLASS = {55U35 (55U10 55U40)},
  MRNUMBER = {4587313},
       DOI = {10.2140/agt.2023.23.509},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.2140/agt.2023.23.509},
} for a modern formulation of the Bousfield-Kan formula.